# What happens to ignored rows when Ignore failure is selected in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

There are 3 components in the data flow: an `OLE DB Source`, `Data Conversion` transformation and a `Flat File Destination`. If I selected the `Ignore failure` option in the Data conversion transformation and some rows get ignored in that data conversion level then would those ignored rows move towards target? Or where can I get those ignored rows? Are those going to available in the log file?

What will happen to erroneous rows when I select `Fail component` as option?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard behavior when you select `Ignore failure` seems to be to ignore the offending values, not the rows that contain them. I just did a quick test (SQL Server 2008 R2) and values are imported with `NULL` instead of the offending values.

You can find a very helpful page with more information on error handling in SSIS Data Flow tasks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141679.aspx). An overview from that page of the relevant error handling options and what they mean:

**Fail Component**:
The Data Flow task fails when an error or a truncation occurs. Failure is the default option for an error and a truncation.

**Ignore Failure**:
The error or the truncation is ignored and the data row is directed to the output of the transformation or source.

**Redirect Row**:
The error or the truncation data row is directed to the error output of the source, transformation, or destination.

Comment: yes thanks.It says the redirected rows can be collected in the out put.              But it does not day anything about what happen to erroneous rows when i select Fail component

Comment: When you select Fail component, the whole task/package will fail when an error is encountered.

Comment: Ok when I select Fail component, the whole task/package will fail when an error is encountered.But in this situation What will happen to that row.Does that row go to the ssis default log file?

Comment: @user1254579: I don't think there's automatic logging of errors unless you configure it yourself. You can see errors in the Error List, but it might indeed be hard to figure out which row caused the failure.

Comment: and there is nothing stopping you from having several data destinations in a row eg:  destination:redirect row-> multicat; logger, destination:ignore failure

Answer (score 1):

As per SQL 2014, if you set Truncate Row Disposition to "RD_IgnoreFailure" the column data will be truncated to the specified length and inserted into destination. For example, if the column size is 50 and the data length is 70, the first 50 characters will be inserted to the destination.

Answer (score -3):

why did you tag sql server 2000 and 2008? Its different on each version, even from 2005 to 2008 it changes. On 2008 you can drag the failed rows to another oledbdestination for example and insert them on a failed-log-table.

Comment: Why did you make this an answer and not a comment on the question?